# Sum of series with conditional convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, conditional-convergence

Sorry for this question, but for some reason I'm stuck on this for few hours already. Before I solved more complex ( I think ) problems, but can't solve this. The only thing I know that this series converge conditionally, but that is just thing you can tell immediately.

${ 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} +\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{10} - \frac{1}{11} - \frac{1}{12} + ... }$

I will be really grateful if someone at least give me hint how to do it.

P.S. In task book where I got this problem it was said I need to use harmonic series partial sum formula, but I cannot find the way to use it here.

Comment: I don't see it either, since it only converges conditionally you cannot reorder the terms.

Comment: You can always reorder the partial sums

Comment: Please submit your solution as an answer, and not as an edit to the question. It is also improper to edit the title to contain the words "SOLVED". To mark your question as solved, you should accept the answer that helped you the most. As such, I have rollbacked your edits.

Answer (score 2):

There's a standard way to do these things. Note that
$${x \over 1 + x^3} = x(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x^3)^n)$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{3n + 1}$$
As a result (I'll leave the rigorousness for you to ponder on),
$$\int_0^1 {x \over 1 + x^3} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 (-1)^n x^{3n + 1}$$
$$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^{n} \over 3n + 2}$$
$$= {1 \over 2} - { 1 \over 5}+ { 1\over 8} -...$$
This gives you one third of the series, and you can do similar integrals for the other two portions of it. If you evaluate these integrals and add the results you'll get the answer.

Your work can be reduced if you recognize one of the other two thirds of the series as a multiple of the alternating series for $\ln 2$. The sum of the integrals for the remaining two thirds will then simplify a bit.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me to recall thing that will probably help me to finish this

Comment: I've done it, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The series of partial sums $S_N$ is

$$ S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac1{6n-5}+\frac1{6n-4}+\frac1{6n-3}-\frac1{6n-2}-\frac1{6n-1}-\frac1{6n}\right)  $$

Comment: I don't quite understand what is it and how I can get this, can you explain please?

Comment: You asked for a hint.  Look at the sum herein and the general terms.  Start with $n=1$.  Do you see that this expression is equivalent to your series as $N\to\infty$?

Comment: After you edited I think I got some ideas, I will thy it now, thanks

Comment: I've done it, thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.

Comment: @teasu873 Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.